# Can't visibly select anything in Object or Edit modes. What have I done?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode, select

I haven't had this happen to me before. I can manipulate stuff in edit mode, but I cant see what. Neither can I see the select borders in object or any other mode. How can I fix this?

Comment: You might have turned off viewport overlays - click the two little overlapping circles in the top-right of the viewport.

Comment: Christopher Bennet, that was it, thanks! Never used that before, didn't even know it existed :)